# cumsum in an xts for values that already sum but reset every year

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

Data:

```
        [,1]
2015-03-17 1
2015-03-18 2
2015-03-19 4
{cont}
2015-12-31 200
2016-01-01 0
2016-12-02 3
2016-12-03 9
```

Since this xts already has the running total within years, I wanted to calculate the running total accross years.

So it looks like

```
           Value   ## cumsum(value) ## not what I want
2015-03-17 1        # 1
2015-03-18 2        # 3
2015-03-19 4        # 7
{cont}              # {cont}
2015-12-31 200      # x, where x is much bigger than 200
2016-01-01 200      # x + x
2016-01-02 203      # 3x + 3
2016-12-03 209      # 4x + 3 + 9
```

I tried using `cumsum` and `mutate` but it returned the running total and didn't change for years.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your data have a running total that that starts at zero at the beginning of every calendar year.  You want the running total across the entire timespan, which is what `cumsum(x)` does.  But you say that doesn't work because, "it returned the running total and didn't change for years", which sounds like exactly what you said you wanted.

Comment: Maybe I'm using `cumsum` wrong, but it's keeping a running total, where as I just want 2015's total (the value provided on 12/31) added to every value in 2016

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. For example, you would want `c(0:5, 0:5)` to become `c(0:5, 0:5 + 5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand your question, here's a solution. The comments hopefully explain what's being done.

```
# Merge original data with year-end values, filling with zeros
y <- merge(x, year.end = apply.yearly(x, last), fill = 0)

# Lag year-end values, so they appear at the start of the following year
y$year.end <- lag(y$year.end)

# Set first NA to zero (so cumsum results aren't all NA)
y$year.end[1] <- 0

# Take a cumulative sum of the year-end values, so they increase each year
y$year.end <- cumsum(y$year.end)

# Add two columns to create running total
y$running.total <- rowSums(y)
```